# How to match array elements from one object into another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to write a proper function to match Calendar_ID busy array from response into clients calendars array items?

This is the code i receive from the Server:

**Init object nr 1**

```
response = {
  calendars: {
    calendarID_1: {
      busy: [{},{}]
    },
    calendarID_2: {
      busy: [{},{}]
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

This is the code I need to merge the data in:

**Init arr nr 2**

```
clients = [
  {
    name: clientName,
    calendars: ["calendarID_1", "calendarID_2"]
  },
  ...
]
```

This is how it should look like after the iterating function:

**Output arr should be**

```
clients = [
  {
    name: clientName,
    calendars: {
      calendarID_1: {
        busy: [{}, {}]
      },
      calendarID_2: {
        busy: [{}, {}]
      },
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

**My attempt were:**

```
for (const calendar in response.calendars) {
    for (const client in clients) {
        clients[client].calendars.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            if (cur === calendar) {
                 acc[cur] = response.calendars[calendar];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: My code is not working, this is what i was thinking might be working, but it is not.

Comment: (1) You don't really have an accumulator in your `.reduce` (you never pass an initial one and you dont return something from the reducer). (2) response.calendars is already a lookup array, use it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Input:
const response = {
  calendars: {
    calendarID_1: {
      content: "of calendar 1",
    },
    calendarID_2: {
      content: "of calendar 2",
    },
    calendarID_3: {
      content: "of calendar 3",
    },
  },
}

const clients = [
  {
    name: "first",
    calendars: ["calendarID_1", "calendarID_2"]
  },
  {
    name: "second",
    calendars: ["calendarID_3"]
  },
    
]



// Solution:

const result = clients.map(client => ({
  ...client,
  calendars: Object.fromEntries(
    client.calendars.map(id => ([ id, response.calendars[id] ]))
  ),
}));

console.log(result);
```

This maps to a new array of clients, spreads the previous client which basically shallow copies the whole array, then it takes the ids of the clients calendars, looks them up in the response and builds a new object from that. That's O(n) to the number of clients calendar ids.

Comment: Thank you so, so, so much! You saved me. I knew the answer shouldn't be complicated. Obviously I have to educate myself more in array/objects manipulations.